# Reducing Errorlog file size

Tags: sql-server

We had a user change a password on an account that was on an automation equipment that pinged the sql server many times a second (for no apparent reason - the pinging).

In the end my errorlog ballooned out to >6gb, and my hard drive isn't large enough to accomodate that.

I've cycled it, but it's still at the 6gb.

Is there a way to reduce that?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure of the exact number, but SQL Server will hang on to the previous 6 errorlog files.

Try the following at least 7 times:

```
EXEC sp_cycle_errorlog;
GO
```

Source: [sp_cycle_errorlog (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182512.aspx)

Comment: We were cycling the sqlagent error log but needed to cycle this one also.